# SkiaSharp with ASP.NET Core on Ubuntu

Tags: asp.net-core, skiasharp

I want to use SkiaSharp on my ASP.NET Core web app on Ubuntu. I have read articles on this but I think I am missing something. Let's say my server is configured well, .NET Core is installed, SkiaSharp is git-cloned/built using the steps in https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp/wiki/Building-on-Linux, my web app is git-cloned+built/deployed+configured, and referencing the SkiaSharp NuGet. When the web app runs, does it automatically use the .so file? If now, how would they work together?

Answer (score 2):

So, just an FYI for those reading this in the future.

Back then, there was not pre-built library for linux, so you had to do your own. Then (what I think the OP is missing) you references the .so file using Content and a CopyToOutput.

Now...

Just reference the [SkiaSharp.NativeAssets.Linux](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SkiaSharp.NativeAssets.Linux) NuGet package.

Comment: Interesting but I have a hard time having it work on ARM32. I did a test on AMD64 Linux and I could draw a bit but ARM32 just fails. The hardest part is there is no exception shown at runtime unless I debug from VS Code.
I did research and I think you took part in this support job. It would be nice to add clear instruction on how to prepare a C# project along target Linux to work properly. For instance it often mention that we must install libfontconfig1. Anything else?
Thanks.